# Modify the guiviewer3d-toolbar

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I would like hide everything in the toolbar except the `measureTools`, which I managed to do using `visibility: hidden` for all of the other tools.

However, the dark background theme is still visible for all three tool-groups (navTools, modelTools, settingsTools).

Everything disappears if I set

```
.dark-theme{
    visibility: hidden;
{
```

And if I modify the `.dark theme{ background-color: rgba(34,34,34,.0);}` it effects the expanded options that shows when the measure tool is clicked.

Any suggestion? Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not, better use the Headless viewer and add a Custom button that access the Autodesk.Measure Extension? By a headless viewer you can refer to this sample 
https://viewer-rocks.autodesk.io/

That one is using custom made extensions that become available when you make the viewer go on full screen mode.

---- EDIT

Is this what you are trying to achieve? Only Measure Tool showing

[image]

Here also is how it looks when you try to use it.

[image]

If this is what you want, you can try using an extension we have called Control Selector, play with the extension and see how it works. 
A live link that uses the extension can be found here.

https://viewer-nodejs-tutorial.herokuapp.com/

And here you can find the Code for the extension, just bare in mind that the extensions were written with ES6 sytanx, so it needs transpiling before it can be used.

https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/library-javascript-viewer-extensions/blob/master/src/Autodesk.ADN.Viewing.Extension.ControlSelector/Autodesk.ADN.Viewing.Extension.ControlSelector.js

Comment: Hi, thanks. However, we have already customized our own app which is where we'd like to do this modification. So, we'll hide the complete toolbar and then create a custom button that access the Autodesk.Measure extenstion. Any example on how I would do this to get the complete functionalities from the measure tool?

Comment: That's perfect. Just what we were looking for 100%! Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Oh, and @jaime, just wanted to share that the link from yesterdays recording, posted here: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/free-webinar-aec-hackathon-starts-tomorrow-noon seems to be wrong. The one we received in the mail today  was correct.

Comment: Oh thanks for letting me know, I will tell Michael to fix it :) Cheers and glad it worked.

Comment: By the way, @Jaime: do you know how I can zoom the starting view (even more than what "fitToView" does)?

Comment: Let me add another answer because I cannot put code in a comment :), Actually make another post and I will reply on that one, I don't want to have 2 answers in this post and confuse future developers :)